# Proof that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$ using standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

I want to prove that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$ using the probability density function given by ($X$ is a random random variable)

$$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

From where $x\in \mathbb{R}$

I am also given the random variable $Y$ given by $Y=X^{2}$ note also that

$$f_{Y}(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2}[f_{X}(\sqrt{y})+f_{X}(-\sqrt{y})] & \text{if $y>0$} \\ 
0 & \text{in another case}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

And

$\Gamma(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t} \, dt$

I think that we should find the cumulative distribution function for $f_{Y}(y)$, for this note that

$$f_{Y}(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2}[f_{X}(\sqrt{y})+f_{X}(-\sqrt{y})] & \text{if $y>0$} \\ 
0 & \text{in another case}
\end{matrix}\right.=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}} & \text{if $y>0$} \\ 
0 & \text{in another case}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

From here, there is nothing concrete that I can see, but we can notice that

\begin{eqnarray} \Gamma(1/2) &=&  \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-1/2}e^{-t}dt  \\  
&=&  \int_{0}^{\infty}  \sqrt{2}z^{-1} e^{-z^2/2}  z \ d z   \qquad \text{ (take $t=\frac{z^2}{2}$ )}  \\  
&=&  \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \sqrt{2} e^{-z^2/2}   \ d z     
\end{eqnarray}

From here, having the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $Y$ it should be possible to deduce something, but it is not clear. Any help for this?

Comment: Where did that $z^2$ in the last integral come from?? (Amusingly, it doesn't actually change the answer.)

Comment: that's right, I'll delete that line

Comment: so then you know from the normal pdf that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx = \sqrt{2\pi} $

Comment: I actually thought of a slightly simpler approach, if we take $t=\frac{z^2}{2}$ we have that
$\Gamma(1/2)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{-z^{2}}{2}}dz=2\sqrt{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\frac{-z^{2}}{2}} dz$

but that's exactly what I don't understand, because if it is a standard normal distribution the integral should take that value, could you explain that a little bit please?

Comment: For any pdf, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)dx = 1.$ So that holds for the normal PDF. Of course to prove that this expression for the pdf is correctly normalized, you actually need to [do the integral somehow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates).

Comment: A more elementary proof [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397122/397200#397200).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the intention is to show that assuming the PDF for the Gaussian is correctly normalized, $\Gamma(1/2)$ needs to take that value.

You can either do that per a normal integral change of variables as you did at the end and discussed in the comments, or you can take an approach with using random variables more directly as you alluded to before (but got the expression slightly wrong).

If $X$ is standard normal, and $Y= X^2,$ then $$ f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} (f_X(\sqrt{y}) + f_X(-\sqrt y))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-y/2},$$ for $y>0,$ so $$ 1=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-y/2}dy = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi z}}e^{-z}dz= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma(1/2)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, but could you explain a little more in detail why $1=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-y/2}dy$ appreciate it!

Comment: @Wrloord Because $\int_0^\infty f_Y(y) dy = 1.$... it's a pdf.

Comment: Ohh, but it was my understanding that this happens when it is the integral since $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: @Wrloord $f_Y(y)=0$ for $y<0$.